# clang: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, clang

I checked multiple questions like this, but none of the answers worked in my case.

I have a simple "hello world!" c program. When I tried to run it using clang, I get the following error:

```
/..//bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/..//bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when I do `-v` it gives me:

```
clang version 3.4 (branches/release_34)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Selected GCC installation: 
 "/nfs/projects/zephyr/Ruturaj/softboundcets-34/softboundcets-llvm-clang34/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name agsd.c -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -target-linker-version 2.29.1 -v -resource-dir /nfs/projects/zephyr/Ruturaj/softboundcets-34/softboundcets-llvm-clang34/Debug+Asserts/bin/../lib/clang/3.4 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /nfs/projects/zephyr/Ruturaj/softboundcets-34/softboundcets-llvm-clang34/Debug+Asserts/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /projects/zephyr/Ruturaj -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 96 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/agsd-ad6d7d.o -x c agsd.c
clang -cc1 version 3.4 based upon LLVM 3.4 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /nfs/projects/zephyr/Ruturaj/softboundcets-34/softboundcets-llvm-clang34/Debug+Asserts/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/..//bin/ld" --hash-style=gnu --no-add-needed --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /lib/../lib64/crt1.o /lib/../lib64/crti.o /lib/../lib64/crtbegin.o -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/agsd-ad6d7d.o -L/usr/lib/ -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed crtend.o /lib/../lib64/crtn.o
/..//bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/..//bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to run it with:

```
clang -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8
```

But, it is still not working.

I installed newer llvm (6.0) and it worked fine. But, I need this 3.4 version to run a project.

Comment: I suggest compiling an object file first (with `-c`), and then invoking the linker directly. Figure out how the new Clang invokes the LD (`-v` shows the command it uses; in this case it starts with `"/..//bin/ld" ...`) and do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Basically I'm trying to reproduce this - https://github.com/santoshn/softboundcets-34 I can compile the file with `-c` but then how can I link the other flags e.g. `../softboundcets-34/softboundcets-lib`?

Comment: As I said, run the new clang (the one that works) with `-v`. See what command it uses to invoke the linker (the `ld`). Then run that command yourself, but using the object file you got from the old clang.

Comment: it worked in that way! thanks so much @HolyBlackCat